# how to get the selected value of a dropdown which is inside a bootstrap modal into a textbox in php

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[[image: It's a Modal Box where selected text of a dropdown not showing in the textbox on change]]

```js
   $( "#ddlcolors" ).change(function() {
    var sel = $( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).val();
    var textbox = document.getElementById("txtmanuid");
    textbox.value =$( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).text();
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
    <select required id="ddlcolors" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
     <option class="text-success" selected disabled value=""><h6>-- Select Colors --</h6></option>
     <option class="text-success text-center" value="R">Red</option>
     <option class="text-success text-center" value="G">Green</option>
     <option class="text-success text-center" value="B">Blue</option>
     <option class="text-success text-center" value="O">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" >
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here what i am trying to achieve: whenever value of a dropdown changes, that same value should be shown in the textbox, which is right next to it.

Please help ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your expected code,

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="container">
             <h2>Modal Example</h2>
             <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
             <!-- Modal -->
             <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                   <!-- Modal content-->
                   <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                         <select required id="ddlcolors" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
                            <option class="text-success" selected disabled value="">
                               <h6>-- Select Colors --</h6>
                            </option>
                            <option class="text-success text-center" value="R">Red</option>
                            <option class="text-success text-center" value="G">Green</option>
                            <option class="text-success text-center" value="B">Blue</option>
                            <option class="text-success text-center" value="O">Orange</option>
                         </select>
                         <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" >
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <script>
             $( "#ddlcolors" ).change(function() {
             var sel = $( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).val();
             var txtman = $( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).text()
             $('#txtmanuid').val(txtman);
             
             });
          </script>  
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem and dedicating some time for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: $( "#btnsend" ).click(function() { var dataid = $(this).data('id'); }

Answer (score 1):

USE this,

```
 $( "#ddlcolors" ).change(function() {
    var sel = $( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).val();
    var textbox = document.getElementById("txtmanuid");
    textbox.value =$( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).text();
    });
```

Use new one,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

        <select required id="ddlcolors" class="text-success form-control input-sm">
            <option class="text-success" selected disabled value=""><h6>-- Select Colors --</h6></option>
            <option class="text-success text-center" value="R">Red</option>
            <option class="text-success text-center" value="G">Green</option>
            <option class="text-success text-center" value="B">Blue</option>
            <option class="text-success text-center" value="O">Orange</option>
        </select>               <input type="text" readonly id="txtmanuid" >

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $( "#ddlcolors" ).change(function() {
        var sel = $( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).val();
        var txtman = $( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).text()
                $('#txtmanuid').val(txtman);
        alert($( "#ddlcolors option:selected" ).text());
        });
        </script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working. Selected value of a dropdown is still not shown in the textbox. Please help. It's urgent,

Comment: Please help me - I have updated the code you sent me in the code snippet. It runs here perfectly but not on my localhost, why??  These are the "JS" I have mentioned :    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       Please guide me where I am wrong??

Comment: why you are add 2 jquery times? use only one

Comment: check my new answer above.

Comment: use any one jquery libray. That is solved your problem.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the code. But my query is not this. If you simply put a <select><option></option></select> inside a body tag, in this way it will work.     But here I am putting <select><option></option></select> inside a bootstrap modal box. Here by putting inside a modal box this script is not working.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3. I remember in asp.net if we put a textbox or a dropdown inside a table. In order to access this textbox or dropdown we have to use table.FindControl. In the same way here in php what I think we have to use something like this so that it can find a dropdown inside a modal box. But how to achieve this I have no idea at all. Please help

Comment: Please have a look at the screenshot I posted in the beginning

Comment: Check above new answer

Comment: No it is still not working. Sir as per your code "<select><option></option></select>" is in a web page. But mine is inside a bootstrap modal. Probably its because of this code is not working. For more clarity of what i am doing n trying to say : Please have a look at the screenshot I posted in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#ddlcolors").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        var textbox = document.getElementById("txtmanuid");
        textbox.value = selectedValue;
    });
```

Add jquery before above code :

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```